# converting to new classnames using open source package

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

- I am new to js.
- I am trying to convert my adding class code to this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames
- bur when I try to do I am not getting proper results, Can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.
- even I saw the example but not able to proceed

```or-tag-here
**actual code**

Const swimmingName = 'sports-basketball' + (this.props.jumping ? ' jumping' : '');

**converted code**

let swimmingName = classnames({
    'sports-basketball' : true,
    'jumping' : this.props.jumping
});


Uncaught ReferenceError: classnames is not defined
    at PlayingSinging.render (swimming.jsx:20)
    at PlayingSinging.<anonymous> (makeAssimilatePrototype.js:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:587)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:607)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as _renderValidatedComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:220)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:37)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:241)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (ReactDOMComponent.js:591)
```

Comment: `let swimmingName = classNames({` (case matters)

Comment: @MichaelCoker can you give some explaination it will help me in future

Comment: @MichaelCoker it would be how they are implementing this logic let swimmingName = classNames({
    'sports-basketball' : true,
    'jumping' : this.props.jumping
});

Comment: I don't use react, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @MichaelCoker will it match this logic ?? Const swimmingName = 'sports-basketball' + (this.props.jumping ? ' jumping' : '');

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not import classnames, so you can try this

```
import classnames from 'classnames'

let swimmingName = classnames({
  'sports-basketball' : true,
  'jumping' : this.props.jumping ? true : false
});
```

Comment: will it match this logic ?? Const swimmingName = 'sports-basketball' + (this.props.jumping ? ' jumping' : '');